# vb6 Compare times in list with current time

Tags: time, vb6, compare

I'm making form where i need to enter the time's for each period like.

1. Start time - End time
2. Start time - End time
3. Start time - End time

Those record's could be saved in listbox as in my example. On another form i have 3 labels
CurrentTime, TimePassed, TimeLeft, and a Timer which ticks in interval 1second. So the time in timepassed ticking up, time left ticking down, and current time show correct time while application is opened.

In final it looks like this

[image]

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Call addp
End Sub

Function addp(Optional ByVal t As String)
Dim s As String, e As String
If t = "" Then s = Trim(InputBox("Start time (hh:mm AM/PM):")) Else: s = Trim(Split(t, "-")(0))
If s = "" Or InStr(1, s, " AM") = 0 And InStr(1, s, " PM") = 0 Then Exit Function
If chk(s) = False Then Exit Function
If t = "" Then e = Trim(InputBox(s & "-?" & vbCrLf & "End time:")) Else: e = Trim(Split(t, "-")(1))
If e = "" Or InStr(1, e, " AM") = 0 And InStr(1, e, " PM") = 0 Then Exit Function
If e = s Then Exit Function
If chk(e) = False Then Exit Function
If Format$(Split(s, "-")(0), "hh:mm AM/PM") > Format$(Split(e, "-")(0), "hh:mm AM/PM") Then Exit Function
If lstPeriods.List(0) <> "" Then
If Format$(Split(lstPeriods.List(lstPeriods.ListCount - 1), "-")(1), "hh:mm AM/PM") > Format$(Split(s, "-")(0), "hh:mm AM/PM") Then Exit Function
End If
lstPeriods.AddItem lstPeriods.ListCount + 1 & ". " & s & "-" & e
If frmMain.lblPeriod.Caption = "" Then Call snd(s & "-" & e, lstPeriods.ListCount)
End Function
```

For check

```
Function chk(ByVal st As String) As Boolean
st = Replace$(Replace$(st, " AM", ""), " PM", "")
If UBound(Split(st, ":")) <> 1 Then Exit Function
For i = 0 To 1
If IsNumeric(Split(st, ":")(i)) = False Then Exit Function
If Len(Split(st, ":")(i)) <> 2 Then Exit Function
If Split(st, ":")(i) < 0 Then Exit Function
Next
If Split(st, ":")(0) > 12 Then Exit Function
If Split(st, ":")(1) > 59 Then Exit Function
chk = True
End Function
```

The solution i gave is the only solution which beginner as i I had. And i know it's confusing and very slow. There is no way this can be finished by using trim/split/format because it require for a lot of modification.

Searching for easier solution.

Sp i need to compare the current time on computer with the time person enetered in textbox/listbox how can i do that .

Comment: Woooaa, please format your code!

Comment: Oh, and using a standard timer to increment time is inaccurate. You should use a start time and a difference as timer ticks can drift and aren't guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Run this code you need to add 5 Controls to the Form1

```
lblSystemTime = Label Control
lblTimeLeft = Label Control
lblTimePassed = Label Control
lblPeriod = Label Control

tmrSystemTime = Timer Control




Dim Periods()


Private Sub Form_Load()

Periods = Array( _
         "06:00 PM-07:00PM", _
        "07:01 PM-08:00PM", _
        "09:00 PM-10:00PM", _
        "1AM-2AM" _
        )


End Sub

Private Sub tmrSystemTime_Timer()

lblSystemTime.Caption = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)

 Dim OnPeriod As Integer
 OnPeriod = GetPeriod()


If OnPeriod < 0 Then

    lblTimeLeft.Caption = vbNullString
    lblTimePassed.Caption = vbNullString
    lblPeriod.Caption = "Unknown Period"

Else
    lblPeriod = CStr(OnPeriod + 1) & ". period"

    lblTimeLeft.Caption = "Time Left: " & Format( _
                                            DateAdd("s", _
                                                    DateDiff("s", _
                                                        CDate(lblSystemTime.Caption), _
                                                        CDate(Split(Periods(OnPeriod), "-")(1))), _
                                                            CDate("0") _
                                                                    ), _
                                                                    "nn:ss" _
                                                                     )





    lblTimePassed.Caption = "Time Passed: " & Format( _
                                            DateAdd("s", _
                                                    DateDiff("s", _
                                                        CDate(Split(Periods(OnPeriod), "-")(1)), _
                                                        CDate(lblSystemTime.Caption)), _
                                                            CDate("0") _
                                                                    ), _
                                                                    "nn:ss" _
                                                                     )





End If



End Sub

Private Function GetPeriod() As Integer

Dim ICount As Integer
For Each Pr In Periods

    If CDate(Split(Pr, "-")(0)) <= CDate(lblSystemTime.Caption) And _
        CDate(Split(Pr, "-")(1)) >= CDate(lblSystemTime.Caption) Then

        GetPeriod = ICount
        Exit Function
    End If


ICount = ICount + 1
Next



GetPeriod = -1

End Function
```

Comment: Yes but this is also a problem i don't need to implement time's in code. I need to read them from textboxes

Comment: @Anel_Hodzic You mean this part is in a textbox?   "06:00 PM-07:00PM", _
        "07:01 PM-08:00PM", _
        "09:00 PM-10:00PM", _
        "1AM-2AM" _ .     If so, you can convert the content of the text to an array to use [split(txtTimePeriod.text,vbcrlf)] will convert the string separated by new line into array of strings.

Comment: Please put some comments in that code to explain what it's doing, and ideally, fix the formatting. The indentation and mass amounts of white space makes it very difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something which may help:

```
Private Sub TimeCheck(byval int_TimeNow as Integer)
  dim intTimeThen as string 'set a variable to compare for the THEN time
  dim intTimeNow as string 'set a variable to compare for the NOW time
  dim intDiff as string ' set a variable for the difference in time

  intTimeNow = int_TimeNow 'just to ensure we don't mess with any data

  intTimeThen = val(txtTimeThen.text) 'get the numeric value of the time, the system will  
                                    'convert it from a string to the value here.

  intDiff = intTimeThen - intTimeNow 'Do the math

  lstTimeEvents.additem timevalue(intDiff) 'write it to a listbox
End Sub
```

I realize this is not the coding convention you are using, but it should demonstrate what you are looking for to some degree.

Comment: Note that VB6 doesn't have a concept of a time period so printing a TimeValue of greater than 1 day will include a date part of 31/12/1899.